# How to import a spreadsheet in IBM Rational DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors, ibm-rational

I have a spreadsheet in CSV format with the following three columns:

```
ID Attribute1 Attribute2
```

`ID` is the unique (absolute?) number that "go to" uses in ***DOORS***. Values are in format ***SRD-123***.
`Attribute1` is a string
`Attribute2` is text

I created this spreadsheet by exporting to Excel from ***DOORS***, and adding the values for the two attributes.

The attributes already exist in ***DOORS*** with no data in them.

I'd like to import this spreadsheet into ***DOORS*** with the goal of automatically entering the values for the attributes. Specifically, `Attribute1` and `Attribute2` would be filled for an already existing ID.

I've tried the ***DOORS*** import feature but haven't had any luck with it. Is this something that ***DOORS*** can do (from the GUI) or is a ***DXL*** script required? Or do I need a more detailed hierarchy for the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

The DOORS GUI's built in import feature will happily accommodate a CSV spreadsheet, which you should be able to convert your excel document into (via Excel).

If you want to keep it as an excel document, you will need to use DXL script.

Answer (score 0):

In Spreadsheet Import, instead of Object ID like *SRD-123*, you need to use Absolute Number *123*

The spreadsheet column Absolute Number must have only the number, not the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question is very simple

ID in DOORS is Legacy ID + Absolute number (unique for each req)
Attribute name 1 --》 Let's say xyz
Attribute name 2 --》 Let's say ABC

So you want to update the values of both xyz and  ABC in DOORS with respect to Excel

For that the process is simple.......
Save your excel file as .txt and then rename .txt to .tsv and then import into doors and content will reflect into doors

Make sure that Excel attributes name and excel attributes name must be equal